# Monotonicity of $\{n^5e^{-n}\}_{n=1}^{n=\infty}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the series, $\{n^5e^{-n}\}_{n=1}^{n=\infty}$ that I wish to check the monotonicity of. I used the ratio test as follows,

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}:\frac{(n+1)^5}{e^{n+1}}\cdot \frac{e^n}{(n)^5} = \frac{1}{e}\big(1 + \frac{1}{n})^{5\hspace{0.1cm}*}$$

I then let $(1 + \frac{1}{n})^5 = e$ to find the value of $n$ which made the expression above in (*) '$1$'. I found that to be approximately $4.52$. I then made the conclusion that, $\forall n \geq 5$, $n^5e^{-n}$ is decreasing monotonically. However, the answers have $\forall n \geq 6$. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: It looks to me like you are right.

Comment: You established that $a_{6}$ is the first term that is smaller than its predecessor. I guess it's a question of interpretation whether one says that the sequence starts to decrease at $n=5$ or $n=6$, but I would say $n=6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

$f(x):= x^5e^{-x}, x>0.$

$f'(x) = 5x^4e^{-x} - x^5e^{-x}=$

$(5x^4-x^5)e^{-x}.$

$f'(x) \lt 0$ implies $f$ strictly decreasing,

$\iff $

$5x^4 -x^5 < 0$, or

$x> 5.$